# MariaDB Installation on NXP LS2088 ARDB : Segmentation Fault

Tags: mysql, c, linux, mariadb, embedded-linux

I am trying to install MariaDB from source code on NXP LS2088 ARDB's linux platform. I am using the following [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/generic-build-instructions/)

When I am trying to start MariaDB for the first time using the command **scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql** in /usr/local/mysql a segmentation fault occurs. Following is the log:

```
>  root@ls2088ardb:/usr/local/mysql# scripts/mysql_install_db
> --user=mysql Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in './dat[ 7936.524512] mysqld[1980]: unhandled level 0 translation fault (11) at 0xf4 a' ... [ 7936.534125] pgd = ffff80006f82f000 [ 7936.538202]
> [ffffffb4459000] *pgd=00000000efa09003, *pud=00000000f03d3003,
> *pmd=000000838e332003, *pte=02e00083749f6f53 [ 7936.548999]  [ 7936.550490] CPU: 0 PID: 1980 Comm: mysqld Not tainted 4.1.8-rt8+gca03abf #1 [ 7936.557444] Hardware name: Freescale Layerscape 2088a RDB Board (DT) [ 7936.563796] task: ffff80006f934880
> ti: ffff80006f9ec000 task.ti: ffff80006f9ec000 [ 7936.571277] PC is at
> 0xffffb4a109ec [ 7936.574757] LR is at 0xffffb4a109e0 [ 7936.578236]
> pc : [<0000ffffb4a109ec>] lr : [<0000ffffb4a109e0>] pstate: 60000000 [
> 7936.585628] sp : 0000ffffde617d00 [ 7936.588934] x29: 0000ffffde617d00 x28: 87c37b91114253d5  [ 7936.594248] x27:
> ffffffffb4459000 x26: 0000000000000000  [ 7936.599558] x25:
> 0000ffffb4452980 x24: 0000ffffb4c99720  [ 7936.604872] x23:
> ff51afd7ed558ccd x22: c4ceb9fe1a85ec53  [ 7936.610181] x21:
> 0000ffffb4c99700 x20: 0000ffffb4459080  [ 7936.615495] x19:
> 0000ffffb44553c8 x18: 00000000000019a0  [ 7936.620807] x17:
> 0000ffffb4c5a6a8 x16: 0000ffffb4a41458  [ 7936.626115] x15:
> ffffffffb4459000 x14: ffffffffb4450000  [ 7936.631428] x13:
> ffffffff00000000 x12: ffffffffb4459000  [ 7936.636736] x11:
> 00000000d50dcc13 x10: 00000000b4450000  [ 7936.642048] x9 :
> 0027ffffb4459000 x8 : 0000000000000000  [ 7936.647357] x7 :
> 00000000000000ff x6 : ff00000000000000  [ 7936.652671] x5 :
> ffff000000000000 x4 : 0000ffff00000000  [ 7936.657978] x3 :
> 0000000000000001 x2 : 0000000000000000  [ 7936.663292] x1 :
> 0000000000009000 x0 : 0000ffffb4a41000  [ 7936.668599] 
> scripts/mysql_install_db: line 417:  1921 Segmentation fault     
> "$mysqld_bootstrap" $defaults "$mysqld_opt" --bootstrap "--
> basedir=$basedir" "--datadir=$ldata" --log-warnings=0
> --loose-skip-innodb --loose-skip-ndbcluster $args --max_allowed_packet= 8M --default-storage-engine=myisam --net_buffer_length=16K
 Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in^M ./data for more information.
```

I checked the logs in ./data folder but there is nothing in it related to the segmentation fault.
What is causing this segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that --datadir=$ldata should have been something else?  Maybe =$data?  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to be use a build system like OpenEmbedded or Yocto. The board is already supported in [meta-freescale](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-freescale/tree/conf/machine/ls2088ardb.conf?h=master) layer.

Comment: But isn't native compilation on the board a lot easier and better than cross compilation?

Comment: Native compilation is never recommended and not really that much easier.

Comment: Any authorized sources for your statement?

Comment: I have already generated the Linux images using Yocto. I have also build maria db on the board itself. The crash occurs when I try to execute the install script.

Comment: No authorized statements but I work in Embedded Linux domain and trying to compile on a ARM target is just plain wrong way of doing things. If you generated a Linux image using Yocto, why build mariadb on the board? Why not include it in the image using Yocto?

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do it.

Comment: I checked the board manual but could not find a way to include a third party software using Yocto? Can you tell me how to do it or a link?